# spring @Transactional not rolling back for rollbackFor=Exception.class

Tags: java, spring-transactions

I need to roll back the transaction if any exception occurs in method solrJ.indexAllergenBulkSlor(), but it's not rolling back the transaction.I have set AUTOCOMMIT to false also.Kindly help.Thanks in advance.
This is how my service impl looks

```
@Service("mcareService")
@Transactional(readOnly = true, value = "oltpTransactionManager")
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    @Override
    @Transactional(value = "oltpTransactionManager",  propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor={Exception.class, SolrServerException.class})
    public boolean saveAllergens(List<AllergenAutoCmp> allergenList) {
        boolean flag = false;
        LOGGER.info("Inside saveAllergens in MCareServiceImpl");
        try {
            allergenAutoCmpRepository.deleteAllergens();
            allergenAutoCmpRepository.saveAllergens(allergenList);
            solrJ.indexAllergenBulkSlor();
            flag = true;
        } catch (SolrServerException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error occured while solr indexing Allergens", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error occured while solr indexing Allergens", e);
        }
        LOGGER.info("returning from saveAllergens in MCareServiceImpl");
        return flag;
    }

}
```

Comment: could you post your spring bean definition ?

Comment: There is no point to `rollbackFor={Exception.class, SolrServerException.class}`, `rollbackFor={Exception.class}` is enough. `rollbackFor` is accepting an exception as an argument and doing rollback in case of that exception or subclass of it. `SolrServerException` is definitely a subclass of `Exception`, so it is not needed to write it.

Answer (score 6):

This is because you catch SolrServerException or IOException, but you did not throw it out. If you understand how @Transational works, you will realize that it wraps codes around your function and trying to catch the RuntimeException. You need to pass the Exception to outer layer.

```
 try {
        allergenAutoCmpRepository.deleteAllergens();
        allergenAutoCmpRepository.saveAllergens(allergenList);
        solrJ.indexAllergenBulkSlor();
        flag = true;
    } catch (SolrServerException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error occurred while solr indexing Allergens", e);
        throw new RuntimeException("SolrServerException occurred! Rollback my transaction.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error occured while solr indexing Allergens", e);
        throw new RuntimeException("IOException occurred! Rollback my transaction.");
    }
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. In the second post, you can see the call to `saveAllergens(bulkInsertList)` is actually a private method call, so @Transactional will not work unless the poster is using some compile time or load time weaving.

Answer (score 2):

Modified the code as suggested, still it's not rolling back.

So instead of

```
@Override
@Transactional(value = "oltpTransactionManager",  propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor={Exception.class, SolrServerException.class})
public boolean saveAllergens(List<AllergenAutoCmp> allergenList) {
    boolean flag = false;
    LOGGER.info("Inside saveAllergens in MCareServiceImpl");
    try {
        allergenAutoCmpRepository.deleteAllergens();
        allergenAutoCmpRepository.saveAllergens(allergenList);
        solrJ.indexAllergenBulkSlor();
        flag = true;
    } catch (SolrServerException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error occured while solr indexing Allergens", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error occured while solr indexing Allergens", e);
    }
    LOGGER.info("returning from saveAllergens in MCareServiceImpl");
    return flag;
}
```

use below one (removed try catch just)

```
@Override
@Transactional(value = "oltpTransactionManager",  propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor={Exception.class, SolrServerException.class})
public boolean saveAllergens(List<AllergenAutoCmp> allergenList) {
    boolean flag = false;
    LOGGER.info("Inside saveAllergens in MCareServiceImpl");
        allergenAutoCmpRepository.deleteAllergens();
        allergenAutoCmpRepository.saveAllergens(allergenList);
        solrJ.indexAllergenBulkSlor();
        flag = true;
    LOGGER.info("returning from saveAllergens in MCareServiceImpl");
    return flag;
}
```

calling from controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public boolean handleFileUpload(
        @ModelAttribute("uploadFile") MultipartFile uploadFile,
        @ModelAttribute("fileType") String fileType) throws Exception {

    LOGGER.info("inside handleFileUpload");

    CommonsMultipartFile aFile = (CommonsMultipartFile) uploadFile;
    boolean flag = false;
    if (aFile != null && aFile.getSize() > 0) {
        flag = macareService.isFileUploaded(fileType, aFile);
    }
    LOGGER.info("exiting handleFileUpload");
    return flag;
}
```

and the method in service which calls saveAllergens(..) method is

```
@Override
public boolean isFileUploaded(String fileType, CommonsMultipartFile aFile) {
    boolean flag = false;

    try {
        if (MCareConstants.ALLERGEN_UPLOAD_FILETYPE.equals(fileType)) {
            ArrayList<AllergenAutoCmp> bulkInsertList = (ArrayList<AllergenAutoCmp>) ExcelUtils
                    .getBulkInsert(fileType, aFile);
            if (bulkInsertList.size() > 0) {
                flag = saveAllergens(bulkInsertList);
            }
        }
        if (MCareConstants.REACTION_UPLOAD_FILETYPE.equals(fileType)) {
            ArrayList<ReactionAutoCmp> bulkInsertList = (ArrayList<ReactionAutoCmp>) ExcelUtils
                    .getBulkInsert(fileType, aFile);
            if (bulkInsertList.size() > 0) {
                flag = saveReactionAutoCmps(bulkInsertList);
            }
        }
        if (MCareConstants.LABTESTS_UPLOAD_FILETYPE.equals(fileType)) {
            ArrayList<LabTestAutoCmp> bulkInsertList = (ArrayList<LabTestAutoCmp>) ExcelUtils
                    .getBulkInsert(fileType, aFile);
            if (bulkInsertList.size() > 0) {
                flag = saveLabTestAutoCmps(bulkInsertList);
            }
        }
        if (MCareConstants.STAFF_UPLOAD_FILETYPE.equals(fileType)) {
            ArrayList<StaffSolrForm> bulkInsertList = (ArrayList<StaffSolrForm>) ExcelUtils
                    .getBulkInsert(fileType, aFile);
            if (bulkInsertList.size() > 0) {
                flag = updateStaffList(bulkInsertList);
            }
        }
        if (MCareConstants.REFERRAL_DOCTOR_UPLOAD_FILETYPE.equals(fileType)) {
            ArrayList<ReferralAutoLookup> bulkInsertList = (ArrayList<ReferralAutoLookup>) ExcelUtils
                    .getBulkInsert(fileType, aFile);
            if (bulkInsertList.size() > 0) {
                flag = saveAllReferralAutolookup(bulkInsertList);
            }
        }
    } catch (HeaderNameNotFoundException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error occured while updating solr indexing");
    } catch (MandatoryValueNotFoundException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error occured while updating solr indexing");
    }catch (SolrServerException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error updating index : ", e);
    }catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error updating index : ", e);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error occured while saving and solr indexing     ReactionAutoCmps", e);
    }
    return flag;
}
```

and the log is as follows

```
2014-04-29 19:14:21 ERROR MCareServiceImpl:405 - Error updating index : 
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: Server refused connection at: http://samplename.com:8090/solr/icd102
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:432)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:221)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:105)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.deleteByQuery(SolrServer.java:293)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.deleteByQuery(SolrServer.java:278)
    at com.bluecapmobile.helper.SolrJ.indexAllergenBulkSlor(SolrJ.java:222)
    at com.bluecapmobile.service.impl.MCareServiceImpl.saveAllergens(MCareServiceImpl.java:103)
    at com.bluecapmobile.service.impl.MCareServiceImpl.isFileUploaded(MCareServiceImpl.java:369)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    2014-04-29 19:14:24.469 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
2014-04-29 19:14:24.469 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@3031bb69]
2014-04-29 19:14:24 DEBUG AbstractTransactionImpl:175 - committing
2014-04-29 19:14:24 DEBUG AbstractFlushingEventListener:149 - Processing flush-time cascades
2014-04-29 19:14:24 DEBUG AbstractFlushingEventListener:189 - Dirty checking collections
2014-04-29 19:14:24 DEBUG AbstractFlushingEventListener:123 - Flushed: 0 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 3 objects
2014-04-29 19:14:24 DEBUG AbstractFlushingEventListener:130 - Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
2014-04-29 19:14:24 DEBUG EntityPrinter:114 - Listing entities:
2014-04-29 19:14:24 DEBUG EntityPrinter:121 - com.bluecapmobile.domain.oltp.AllergenAutoCmp{alergen=Wheat, allergenId=472, description=Description, type=Food}
2014-04-29 19:14:24 DEBUG EntityPrinter:121 - com.bluecapmobile.domain.oltp.AllergenAutoCmp{alergen=Soy, allergenId=473, description=Description 1, type=Food}
2014-04-29 19:14:24 DEBUG EntityPrinter:121 - com.bluecapmobile.domain.oltp.AllergenAutoCmp{alergen=test, allergenId=474, description=test, type=test}
2014-04-29 19:14:24 DEBUG JdbcTransaction:113 - committed JDBC Connection
2014-04-29 19:14:24 DEBUG JdbcTransaction:126 - re-enabling autocommit
2014-04-29 19:14:24 DEBUG LogicalConnectionImpl:212 - Aggressively releasing JDBC connection
2014-04-29 19:14:24 DEBUG LogicalConnectionImpl:246 - Releasing JDBC connection
2014-04-29 19:14:24 DEBUG LogicalConnectionImpl:264 - Released JDBC connection
2014-04-29 19:14:24.496 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Closing JPA EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@3031bb69] after transaction
2014-04-29 19:14:24.497 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.o.j.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Closing JPA EntityManager
```

This is how my transacton manager config looks like

```
@Bean ( name = "mtdmEntityManger" )
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean configureMtdmEntityManagerFactory ()
{
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean ();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan ( "com.sample.domain.mtdm" );
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass ( HibernatePersistenceProvider.class );

    Properties jpaProterties = new Properties ();
    jpaProterties.put ( Environment.DIALECT, dialect );
    jpaProterties.put ( Environment.FORMAT_SQL, formatSql );
    jpaProterties.put ( Environment.GENERATE_STATISTICS, true );
    jpaProterties.put ( Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, hbm2ddlAuto );
    jpaProterties.put ( "hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", hibernateNamingStrategy );
    jpaProterties.put ( Environment.SHOW_SQL, showSql );
    jpaProterties.put ( Environment.FORMAT_SQL, formatSql );
    jpaProterties.put ( Environment.RELEASE_CONNECTIONS, connectionReleaseStrategy );
    jpaProterties.put ( Environment.DIALECT, dialect );
    jpaProterties.put ( Environment.DATASOURCE, dataSourceMtdm );
    jpaProterties.put ( Environment.AUTOCOMMIT, false );
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties ( jpaProterties );

    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}

@Bean ( name = "mtdmTransactionManager" )
public PlatformTransactionManager annotationMtdmDrivenTransactionManager ()
{
    JpaTransactionManager mtdmTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager ();
    mtdmTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory ( configureMtdmEntityManagerFactory ().getObject () );
    return mtdmTransactionManager;
}
```

Comment: it looks like its an Error not exception and both are different in Java and transaction roll back only for exception not for error..

Comment: i am getting an exception like this, org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: Server refused connection at: http://samplename.com:8090/solr/icd102 at at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:432)

Comment: is it this solrJ.indexAllergenBulkSlor(); method definition is throwing the exception or handling it?

Comment: solrJ.indexAllergenBulkSlor() method throwing exception not catching any exceptions in this method

Comment: Hi , add  also for rollbackFor={RuntimeException.class,other exceptions}...and one more thing are you using plain sql instead of hibernate query for DB operations by any chance ?

Comment: entityManager.createQuery("DELETE FROM AllergenAutoCmp").executeUpdate() and saving i am using for (AllergenAutoCmp allergen : allergenList) {
   create(allergen);
  }

Comment: are you using emtityManager.persist() for saving each allergen ? and one more thing add  rollbackFor={RuntimeException.class,your other exceptions}..let me know the result

Comment: i added rollbackFor={RuntimeException.class,other exceptions..} and i am using emtityManager.persist() for saving each allergen stilli not able to roll back the transaction

Comment: hey where you have added <tx:annotation-driven> tag ? show that file and other config files you used for more debugging of your problem

Comment: added the transaction configurations, please check and let me know.

Comment: okie..add this @Bean containing class to spring application context..otherwise transaction will not be managed by spring proxy..add the package of this class with component scan of spring config file..or define complete transaction inside spring container file.

Comment: As commented under Po-Ting Huang's (correct) answer, @Transactional will have no effect here since you are calling a private method in the same bean.